# passing ls variable to grep when doing a file search only works inside directory

Tags: grep, find, ls, filenames

I am running a command that I use to find the most recent file in a folder then grep the contents for a matching pattern. Here is the command flow that shows the problem I am having.

```
root@backup /]# grep -w 'sucessfully completed.' "$(ls -1rt /var/log/folder | tail -n1)"
/bin/grep: <file_name>: No such file or directory
[root@backup /]# cd /var/log/folder/
[root@backup file_folder]# grep -w 'sucessfully completed.' "$(ls -1rt /var/log/folder | tail -n1)"
sucessfully completed.
```

In the first command, it finds the file but then says no such file or directory. Weird. Then, as you can see I cd'd inside the actual folder ran the same command and it worked. My variable has the absolute path so what is going on here? I have checked for any grep aliases that could be interfering and found none. If I run the commands separately outside of using a variable it works and it works outside of the files folder. (as I would expect)

```
[root@backup /]# grep -w 'sucessfully completed' /var/log/folder/file
sucessfully completed.
```

Comment: your `ls -1rt | tail -n1` only returned filename, not a full path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dirname of file is missing in first part, try

```
grep -w 'sucessfully completed.' "/var/log/folder/$(ls -1rt /var/log/folder | tail -n1)"
```

do not try ... unles there is no dir in /var/log/folder/

```
grep -w 'sucessfully completed.' "$(ls -1rt /var/log/folder/* | tail -n1)"
```

Comment: Awesome. There was another dir inside the folder I was searching.